# Getting data from an Excel datatable using OLEDB

Tags: vb.net, excel, datatable, oledb

I have an excel 2007 xlsm file, where on one of the tabs I have several data tables. Using VB.NET, I'm trying to read one table at a time as a named range like so:

```
Public Function OpeDataFromRange(ByVal Filename as string, ByVal RangeName As String, ByVal bColumnNames As Boolean) as DataTable
    ' Returns a DataSet containing information from a named range
    ' in the passed Excel worksheet
    Dim sHDR As String
    Dim strConn As String
    If bColumnNames Then
        sHDR = "Yes"
    Else
        sHDR = "No"
    End If


    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & Filename & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=" & sHDR & """;"



    Dim objConn _
        As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConn)
    objConn.Open()
    ' Create objects ready to grab data
    Dim objCmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand( _
        "SELECT * FROM [" & RangeName & "]", objConn)
    Dim objDA As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
    objDA.SelectCommand = objCmd
    ' Fill DataSet
    Dim objDS As New System.Data.DataSet()
    objDA.Fill(objDS)
    ' Clean up and return DataSet
    objConn.Close()

    return objDS


End Function
```

But I'm getting the error at Fill command:

*The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'MyNamedTable1'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.*

I tried to read the entire sheet in the SELECT, and then to fish out my table through objDS.Tables, but then Tables gets loaded with only one table with everything in it.

Any Recommendations?

Comment: Start by turning on Option Strict.  Your function is defined as returning DataTable, but you actually return a DataSet; `on one of the tabs I have several data tables` this is odd too DataTable are data objects and do not have a UI display, so its unclear what you have.

Comment: It's probably called MyNamedTable1$. Use objConn.GetSchema("Tables") to get a list of tables in the file and iterate through them to see what your Named Range is called.

Comment: Ptutonix, yes the function should return DataSet. I was converting it from a Sub for this post and I missed it.  By Data tables I mean excel tables.

Comment: Ciaran, I tried "SELECT * FROM MyNamedTable1$" and I got "Syntax Error in FROM clause". I also tried "SELECT * FROM [MyNamedTable1$]" and i got "'MyNamedTable1$' is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long."

Comment: Ciaran, I run objConn.GetSchema("Tables") and the tables listed correspond mostly to names of indovidual worksheets. There are some other names but those are not of the tables defined within my worksheets (ie. not the names from Formulas->Name manager)

Comment: Then that Named Range is not in the file you are opening.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 with Excel 12.0 you should use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 instead.

Incidentally, you are filling a DataSet but returning a DataTable you need to change one of those.

Personally I prefer to use a DataTable for this but you may prefer a DataSet. If you want to use a DataTable you can...

```
Dim objDT As New DataTable
objDT.Load(objCmd.ExecuteReader)
```

Comment: Ciaran, I did try to use ACE.OLEDB. 12.0, but I was getting "ould not find installable ISAM" error. I followed the advice from this article and switched to OLEDB 4.0 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d7918d9-00ba-43b3-98f2-dca3aa9cca06/could-not-find-installable-isam-while-importing-excel-file?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: Do you actually have it installed? It's pretty standard these days but I guess it's possible you don't have it. Use Regedit and see if you've a key for it. i.e. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: Yes It's installed. I've used another way of connection, using OleDbConnectionStringBuilder and now I'm able to connect using ACE.OLEDB. 12.0 , but I got the same error when trying to query my table: "The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'MyNamedTable1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly." It seems that table names are not listed in the Schema table (see my comment about using GetSchema).

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing the correct file name, that the file exists and you have access to it? Aside from that I am at a loss. Your code works just fine for me.